# Destructuring error objects works in Chrome but not Firefox. What can be done?

Tags: javascript, firefox, error-handling, cross-browser

Imagine the following piece of code:

```js
class FakeError extends Error {
  constructor(message, opts = {}) {
    super(message);
    const { description = null } = opts;
    this.description = description;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

(() => {
  try {
    throw new FakeError('Test', { description: 'This is a test' });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log({ ...error, test: 'test' });
  }
})();
```

In Chrome, this comes out with the desired response, which is to treat the error as if it were a normal object:

```
[object Object] {
  description: "This is a test",
  test: "test"
}
```

However, in Firefox it just ignores the properties added in the prototype extension:

```
[object Object] {
  test: "test"
}
```

Is there a known reason for this? Is there something I can do to make it work cross browser?

Comment: Object spread is a part of ES7 and is not available in all browsers. Note, its not same as Array spread operator. Also, could you share your FF's version?

Comment: @Rajesh Not true.. it is available in es6 and now widely supported

Comment: @xdeepakv that is Array spread. `...` has 2 implementations, one for Array which is in ES6 and another for Object which is in ES7. They look and feel same but are internally different and have different compatibility. I'll look if I can find a reference for this. **[This](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/spread-operator-and-destructuring-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript-2f5578e1252b)** maybe helpful

Comment: It is not the issue here. Issue is that, if description is null it doen't print. If description has value it is working .. I tested.

Comment: issue is `Error.captureStackTrace`, not working properly in Firefox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack

Comment: I should add that I am sending this code through Babel so the destructuring element isn't important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is actually with the `Error.captureStackTrace`, which is not not in the standard and not available in all browsers.

Check the fix:

```js
class FakeError extends Error {
  constructor(message, opts = {}) {
    super(message);
    const { description = null } = opts;
    this.description = description;
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
  }
}

(() => {
  try {
    throw new FakeError('Test', { description: 'This is a test' });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log({ ...error, test: 'test' });
  }
})();
```

Comment: Aaah! I knew it had to be somewhat of a red herring somewhere. Thanks